# ActionMailer and Rspec: Unable to find a browser command (Rails 5.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I have upgraded rails `4.2.11.1` to `5.2.8.1`, and `ActionMailer` stopped working within Rspec.

When I run this simple welcome email ([described on their page](https://%20https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.8.1/action_mailer_basics.html#calling-the-mailer)):

```rb
UserMailer.with(user: @user).welcome_email.deliver_now
```

It returns the following internal server error (500):

```
Unable to find a browser command. If this is unexpected, 
Please rerun with environment variable LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true
or the '-d' commandline option and file a bug at
https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/new
```

I have the following configuration:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

When running with the env var `LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true` it returns:

```
 InternalMailer#welcome_email: processed outbound mail in 10.0ms
 Sent mail to admin@example.com (18.2ms)
 Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2023 18:52:30 +0000
 From: example@example.com
 To: example@example.com
 Message-ID: <63d2cbee2134b_d2ad277028a04983aa@238604b1f73f.mail>
 Subject: Welcome to My Awesome Site
 Mime-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/plain;
  charset=UTF-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
   </head>
   <body>
 <h1> testing</h1>
   </body>
 </html>
```

The same happens if I try to run it within a controller.

Did I miss any breaking changes?